# TextField height not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, flash-cs5

I'm creating a Word processing Flash desktop app, i created an INPUT text field where the user can type text and play with it, i gave it the following parameters:

```
//creating a the Text field
var tfield:TextField = new TextField();

//Position & Dimensions
tfield.x=0;
tfield.y=160;
tfield.width = 1280;
tfield.height = 600;  // <<<==== where the probleme is

//Options
tfield.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
tfield.background=true;
tfield.border=true;
tfield.multiline=true;
tfield.wordWrap = true;

//Add text field to stage
stage.addChild(tfield);
```

Everything works fine except the `tfield.height = 600;` the text field takes the height of one line, and if i add a 2nd or 3rd line, then it expands.

App image: https://image.ibb.co/en5BEm/qsd.png

Adding some lines: https://image.ibb.co/i7HmfR/2nd.png

I want it to be exactly 600px. any ideas?

Comment: Chek if you can set your textfield's `autoSize` property to `TextFieldAutoSize.NONE` and then set size. AS3 manual says "none" is default, but it's kind of possible for them to change the default to "left" and make it auto-resize textfields.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: I converted that comment to an answer. You can now accept it with a "tick" to show others that the question actually has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is related to [TextField's `autoSize` property](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize), which alters its height and width depending on text inside and `multiline` property. To set the fixed height, assign this property a value of `TextFieldAutoSize.NONE`. This will disable automatic resize of a text field.